# Bookshelfjs ORM How to get or see SQL statement its building

Tags: sql, node.js, express, orm, bookshelf.js

When building ORM query, I want to see what the actual (raw) query is that is executed.

For example in Rails we can do like this:

```
User.where(name: 'Oscar').to_sql
# => SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."name" = 'Oscar'
```

This feature present in Bookshelfjs? or any other way to get this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like there is no direct way to get SQL statement like Rails produce..

You can use .[query()](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-query) .[toSQL()](http://knexjs.org/#Other-toSQL) or .[query()](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-query) .[toString()](http://knexjs.org/#Other-toString). But achieving exact result as in Rails is a bit more complicated as queries may be not complete. The cause is that many statements get applied just before performing the query in Bookshelf. For example Bookshelf relations behave so. Also many plugins use events to apply query statements. If you want to debug the queries then I would suggest you to use [Knex#debug](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-debug) instead. For example

```
model.query(function(qb) {
  qb.debug(true);
}).fetch()
```

It prints the debug info in the console.

Source: from officials [bookshelfjs github](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/1319#issuecomment-232005974)

Comment: This option is a lifesaver. Thanks.